# How to proxy HLS m3u8 in PHP

Tags: php, proxy, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I'm trying to proxy HLS and change user agent, everything is working and no error, also when visiting the URL the file will download with .m3u8 extension , but the problem is that not playing, video player is not a problem because several test stream is working.

This is my code

```
public function proxify($args = NULL) {
  $useragent = $this->request->get("ua");
  $url = $this->request->get("url");

  if($useragent != '' && $url != '') {

    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array(
    'User-Agent: ' . $useragent,
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); 

    $request = curl_exec($ch);

    header('Content-Type: video/mp2t');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($url) . '"');
    echo $request;

  } else {
    die('No URL Request found');
    exit();
  }

}
```

What is the problem why is not playing ?, and checking network tab the response code is 200

Thanks, Appreciated

Comment: Where are you playing that file? In browser?

Comment: yes, i'll tried it on browser and VLC and not working, CORS is already allowed so there is no problem

Comment: Maybe you need this: [https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/)

Comment: no, i use that before, as i said video player is not problem, maybe my code implementation

Comment: Did you proxy just the playlist (`.m3u8`)? If so then you need to also proxy the other playlists or media segments referenced by that playlist. See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/AboutHTTPLiveStreaming/Art/stream_playlists_2x.png) for a quick overview.

Comment: Why not configure your web server to do this for you?  It would be much more efficient.

Comment: sorry but i have don't access to the stream server i want to change user agent because the stream play on android only so i need to change user agent to play in other platform